# Python: What does '/' do in a function definition?

Tags: python

`def my_func(x, y, /, *, z = True):`

What does the '/' and '*' do in this implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asterisk (*) and forward slash (/) define whether you can pass positional or keyword arguments to your functions.

The forward slash, when used in parameter list, indicates that all parameters to the left of it must be positional-only.

The asterisk, similarly, indicates that all parameters to the right of it must be keyword-only.